# Return a formula value to a cell and add to existing data in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation

In `Google-Spreadsheet` I have the below setup

```
B3 is set up using "Custom Formatting" : ##"°F/"##"°C"
B2 contains the formula: =ROUND(CONVERT(B3, "F", "C"))

B3=90
B2=32
```

What I desire to happen:

```
Input 90 into B3 resulting in Output B3 "90°F/32°C"; and, no visible output in B2.
```

I'm thinking to `=CONCATENATE(B3,B2)` but, I get infinite loop error.
I would then like to repeat the formula in `B2 for B4, B5, B6, etc`.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand... you want to input a number in b3 and you want the cell to show the value for both °C and °F?

Answer (score 0):

B3: 90
C3: =IF(B3,CONVERT(B3, "F", "C"),)

Format B3: 0.0"°F"
Format C3: 0.0"°C";"-"0.0"°C"

Copy formula to other cells using "click & drag" method